# Nhibernate Fluent update schema without data removing

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, code-first

I'm using NHibernate Fluent Code First for c# desktop app. Is there a way to update db schema without removing existing data.
In my case I need simply add a new column with no constraints, allows nulls, and not a foreign/primary key, but I need to save all the existing data in db.

The db is Postgre 9.2 if it matters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fluentConfiguration.ExposeConfiguration(config => new SchemaUpdate(config).Execute(false, true))` updates database schema automatically and doesn't change existing data. It can only add tables or columns. 
Rename and delete can be executed with FluentMigrator but then you have to manually write data migrations if you need to save your data.